# React useRef and click event passing extra param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

Is it possible to send extra params with a click event via a useRef.

```
const button = useRef(null)

const handleSelectSearchResult = (query, type, extra) => {
    dispatch(search.setSearchQuery(query, type));
    extra && handleFocusWhere();
};


<div ref={button} onClick={() => handleSelectSearchResult(name, category)}>
```

I want to pass the extra param if it is programatically clicked rather than mouse or enter.

button.current.click(send some extra params);

Answer (score 0):

You can use **event.isTrusted** property to differentiate between clicks from the browser or the user triggered in the event triggered by onClick. event.isTrusted is false if the event is from programmatically.
I don't think you can pass parameters from button.click()

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach for what you want to achieve could be [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) your function. Which essentially transforms it into a function that returns another function (a creator function if you will).

```js
const handleSelectSearchResult = isClick => (query, type) => {
    dispatch(search.setSearchQuery(query, type));
    isClick && handleFocusWhere();
};

const handleClickSelectSearchResult = handleSelectSearchResult(true)
const handleEnterSelectSearchResult = handleSelectSearchResult(false)


<div ref={button} onClick={() => handleClickSelectSearchResult(name, category)}>

<OtherComponent onEnter={() => handleEnterSelectSearchResult(name, category)}>
```